# Prompt user to enter values until the same value is entered thrice in a row

Tags: java

I have a question regarding loops. Basically the program rotates around prompting user to enter integers until three integers have been entered which are the same ones but the issue is if i enter a different integer at the beginning and then enter three same integer i am not able to make my program accept it as three similar integer in the row..

This is the actual question: *Write a Java program that prompts the user to enter integers from the keyboard one at a time. The program stops reading integers once the user enters the same value three times consecutively (meaning three times in a row, one after the other).  Once input is completed the program is to display the message “Same entered 3 in a row*
output:

> Enter an integer: 77
>   Enter an integer: 56
>   Enter an integer: 56
>   Enter an integer: 78
>   Enter an integer: 56
>   Enter an integer: 22
>   Enter an integer: 22
>   Enter an integer: 22
>
> Same integer value entered thrice

I am not able to get the above output correctly. Can anyone please help me in this..

Here is the same program which i tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Naim5c
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int count = 0;
       int a,b,c;
       do{
          System.out.println("enter an integer");
          a = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println("enter an integer");
          b = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println("enter an integer");
          c = input.nextInt();
          if(a==b)
          {
             if(b==c)
             {
                System.out.println("Same integer entered thrice");
             }
          }

          else if (b==c) 
          {
             System.out.println("enter an integer");
             a = input.nextInt();
             if(c==a)
             {
                System.out.println("Same integer entered thrice");
             }       
          }
          //System.out.println("enter an integer");
          //a = input.nextInt();
          else if (c==a)
          {
             System.out.println("enter an integer");
             b = input.nextInt();
             if( a==b )
             {
                System.out.println("Same integer entered thrice");
             }       
          }
       }while(a!=b && b!=c);
    }
 }
```

Comment: It'll be easier if you read one variable per loop iteration, not three.

Comment: It's going on the basics of Java. You should also look through `do...while` loop for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of it (at least according to you) you require the need to detect when a User enters three integer numbers of the same value three times in a row rather than throughout the entire entry cycle. All you really need is a counter variable and another integer variable to hold the previously entered value. Something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int a;  // To hold User's current entry value.
int count = 0;  // To hold the number of times the same value was entered.
int prevInt = 0;  // To hold the value previously entered.
do{
    // Since we're in a loop we only need to have
    // a single prompt.
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: --> ");
    a = input.nextInt();   // Get User Input
    // Is User entry equal to what what entered
    // previously?
    if (a == prevInt) { 
        // Yes it is...
        count++;    // Increment our counter
        // if our counter reaches 3 then let's
        // break out of our do/loop.
        if (count == 3) { break; }
        // Otherwise let's continue the loop from
        // the start.
        continue; 
    }
    // Nope, not equal to the User's last entry so
    // let's make prevInt hold the Users new entry.
    prevInt = a;
    // Let's reset our counter to 1. We need to set
    // to 1 because the last User's input which is 
    // now held in prevInt is the actual first entry
    // for the new integer value.
    count = 1;
} while(count < 3);  // Keep looping if our counter is less than 3

// Display that a triple entry was made.
System.out.println("Same integer (" + a + ") entered thrice");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need three variables. Just one variable for remembering the last int and a counter variable for recording how many times you've seen the last integer.

> ```
>      int count = 0;
>      Integer prevInt = null;
>      do {
>          System.out.println("enter an integer");
>          int i = input.nextInt();
>          if (prevInt == null || i != prevInt) {
>              count = 1;
>          } else {
>              count++;
>          }
>          prevInt = i;
>      } while (count != 3);
>      System.out.println("Same integer value entered thrice");
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It became easy for me to understand now. Wasn't using the count concept in my programs for a while. So maybe that became a drawback for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = 0; //holds the current input
boolean check = false; // checking for the input
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
do {
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    num = input.nextInt();
    number.add(num); // add the current input to the array list
    if (number.size() >= 3) { // check if there's 3 or more values in the array
        if (number.get(number.size() - 1) == number.get(number.size() - 2) && number.get(number.size() - 2) == number.get(number.size() - 3)) 
        { // check for input if the same
            check = true;
            System.out.println("\nSame integer value entered thrice");
        }
    }
} while(check == false); 
// checking for loop to continue of no 3 consecutive input of number is the same
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello if you want to make a loop you need the for command. And loops uses arrays

```
int[] I = new int[3]
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{
    System.out.println("enter an integer");
    I[j] =input.nextInt();
}

 if(I[0]==I[1] || I[1]==I[2]){
    System.out.println("Same integer entered thrice");
    continue; 
 }
```

Assume that code is inside your do while code. Feel free to reply if you have questions

You should simply loop everything back to inputing using "continue".